# Display PHP errors

Tags: php

I have a problem with hosting and the hosting company does not want to help me with this. I want to show PHP errors for developing but when there is an error on the page I only see a blank page. I can't use `.htaccess` because the server API is CGI/FastCGI and `php.ini` does not work. I tried this in `php.ini` but it doesn't work, still a blank page, and I made an error in PHP on purpose.

```
display_errors = On
display_startup_errors = On
```

On the page I also have:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

EDIT: Solved by mario, I renamed `php.ini` to `.user.ini` and it worked.

Comment: Can you create two other files. One just prints Hello World, so that you know that PHP is working properly; another one with a known syntax error, and see the output?

Comment: On recent FastCGI setups you can use `.user.ini`, as explained in the manual.

Comment: @mario manual link for the lazy - http://php.net/manual/configuration.file.per-user.php

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

in your PHP file. Source: http://www.dzone.com/snippets/let-php-show-all-errors